# PHP while loop not proceeding in the 2nd while loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch row so i can print it on my table. But the problem is that, the code only runs on the 1st while loop. After it fetch all the rows in the table, it stops there.

`Assuming that I have 5 rows in my tblUnit

```
while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo " <script type'text/javascript'> alert('1');</script>";
    $unitStatus = $r['unitStatus'];
    $unitNumber = $r['unitNumber'];
    $floorNumber = $r['floorCode'];
    $unitType = $r['unitType'];
    $t = $db->query("select floorLevel from tblFloors where floorID = $floorNumber");
    $w = $db->query("select unitTypeName from tblUnitType where unitTypeID = $unitType");
    while ($u = $t->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo " <script type'text/javascript'> alert('2');</script>";
        $floorLevel = $u['floorLevel'];
        while ($x = $w->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo " <script type'text/javascript'> alert('3');</script>";
            ....
            ...
            ..
        }
    }
}
```

The output(`In alert box`):

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

I'm using MS SQL Server for my database.

Comment: So many nested `while`s .. are you sure, one query using `JOIN` wouldn't simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a string evalueting problem  try thsi way

```
$t = $db->query("select floorLevel from tblFloors where floorID = " .  $floorNumber .";");                              
$w = $db->query("select unitTypeName from tblUnitType where unitTypeID = " . $unitType . ";");
```

or

```
$t = $db->query("select floorLevel from tblFloors where floorID = '$floorNumber' ;");
```

Otherwise your $floorNumber don't contain the aspected result

Comment: Thank you! In my database, there were no matching value for `floorID` recorded.